# AWS Systems Manager Bug?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are currently assisting a customer with an issue they're having, and the solution was to use AWS SSM to copy a file from an s3 bucket to a windows directory location.

When we go to 'setup inventory' and select manually target all of the instances, only the instances in availability zone - EU-WEST-2A appear, whilst the instances in 2b and 2c aren't available, and when we try to make API calls to see if SSM is installed using the instance-id, no information is returned. Suggesting that the SSM agent is not installed on the windows instances in the 2b and 2c AZ's.

Has anyone encountered anything like this before? Are we doing something wrong?

Would've posted this on AWS forums but we dont have premium support.

Answer (score 1):

Do all the instances have the same **IAM Role**?

For SSM to work there are a couple of prerequisities:

1. The instances must have **access to `ssm.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com`** - either through IGW if they have a public IP, or through NAT if they are in a private subnet.

   Can you `ping ssm.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` from all the instances?
2. The instance **IAM Role** must have permission to connect to SSM. Make sure that the IAM Roles have **`AmazonEC2RoleforSSM`** policy attached.
3. The **SSM agent** must be installed and running.

Check the connectivity, check the IAM role policies and check the agent. It will be one of these things.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: 1. All of the instances have the same instance profile applied (one we created for the SSM Role)
2. They are all using the same internet gateway and all have a public IP address.
3. AmazonEC2RoleforSSM is in the role we created
4. Also can't check this at this time, but all of the machines were created 2018 or later from the same windows image. So it should be installed by default.

Network setup is 1 VPC, 3 subnets across 3 az's, 1 route table, all subnets using the same route table. Single internet gateway attached to the VPC

We recreated the problem in a seperate AWS account.

Comment: @RossWilliams Hmm that looks all good then. I would double check that the instances can ping the ssm endpoint and that the agent is running. Other than that it’s hard to tell what’s wrong without having access to your instances. Your best bet probably is to subscribe to *Business support* for a month ($100/month) and get them to have a look. You can try *Developer support* that’s cheaper but you can’t use phone or chat.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, and the solution.

It seems the base AMI is causing some issues. 
What has happened is, the windows instance was created in availability zone A, and when its created, the AWS middleware configures some routes into the windows network configuration for that availability zone, which points at the gateway of that subnet(AZ):

Current config:

```
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
  169.254.169.254  255.255.255.255       172.31.0.1      25
  169.254.169.250  255.255.255.255       172.31.0.1      25
  169.254.169.251  255.255.255.255       172.31.0.1      25
```

But when you clone that AMI and deploy it into a different subnet(AZ), the routes do not change.  This is what it should look like;

```
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
  169.254.169.254  255.255.255.255      172.31.32.1      25
 169.254.169.250  255.255.255.255      172.31.32.1      25
  169.254.169.251  255.255.255.255      172.31.32.1      25
```

To get it in the desired state, there is a script included in the AMI located at: `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\initializeinstance.ps1`

Running this script fixed the issue, and the instance now appears in SSM.